# Simple AM-GM inequality

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=3$, using only AM-GM inequalities show that
$$
a+b+c \geq ab+bc+ca
$$
I was able to prove that
$$
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2+c^2 &=\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}+\frac{b^2+c^2}{2}+\frac{a^2+c^2}{2} \geq \\
&\ge  \frac{2\sqrt{a^2b^2}}{2}+\frac{2\sqrt{b^2c^2}}{2}+\frac{2\sqrt{a^2c^2}}{2} \\
&= ab+bc+ca
\end{align}
$$

but now I am stuck. I don't know how to use the fact that $a+b+c=3$ to prove the inequality. Anybody can give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Update:*** *Upps, that is the same as that of @Vincent, sorry didn't see that first. However, it's a bit more explicte*

---

A nicer way to use your results and proceed frm there is the following. You've got that
$$ a^2+b^2+c^2 \ge ab+bc+ca $$
Now use the fact that $(a+b+c)=S=3$ and multiply each side of your original inequality by S this is
$$ (a+b+c)S \ge S(ab+bc+ca)$$
or, *(where we use now that $S=3$)*
$$ (a+b+c)(a+b+c) \ge 3(ab+bc+ca)$$
Then
$$ a^2+b^2+c^2 + 2(ab+bc+ca) \ge 3(ab+bc+ca)$$
and
$$ a^2+b^2+c^2  \ge ab+bc+ca$$
which is exactly that, what you've already proven on your own.

Comment: It was that easy! I didn't see it, thank you.

Comment: Ok, but now that I think about it... How to proceed from that? Any idea?

Comment: hmm, after that you've done the work, and you can proceed to the cafeteria... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

$$9=(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)\geq 3(ab+bc+ca)$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Multiply the original inequality by $a+b+c$ on the LHS and $3$ on the RHS, expand and eliminate common terms and you will arrive at something you have proved.

Answer (score 1):

$9 = (a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2(ab+bc+ac) \geq 3(ab+bc + ac)$

Answer (score 1):

Reformulate first $a+b+c=S$ and $a=M+d \qquad b=M-d $ then

$$S  \ge M^2-d^2 + (S-2M)2M$$
reorganize
$$ 3M^2-2SM+S  +d^2  \ge 0 $$

Now make use of the given definition that $S=3$. We get
$$3(M^2-2M+1)  +d^2  \ge 0 $$
$$3(M-1)^2 +d^2  \ge 0 $$
which is always true.

Well, this focuses "when and how" it makes sense to introduce the condition that $S=3$. Unfortunately the step with the AM-GM-inequality is lost. But maybe you can combine your steps with this derivations?